# Bluehost MySQLi configuration issue

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have the following script, It's working perfectly on my local machine (XAMPP v3.1.0 php v.5.4.7) but when I upload to my web server (Bluehost php v5.4.13) it doesn't work.

My tables are fine & the data I'm giving it is valid.

```
// Connect to DB
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","{USER_NAME}","{PASSWORD}","{TABLE_NAME}");
// Escaped post variables before SQL lookup
    // $email is valid -  "john@john.com";
$escapedEmail = $mysqli->real_escape_string($email);
$retrievedPassword = "";
$getUserPasswordQuery = "Select * FROM User Where Email='{$escapedEmail}'";
$loggedInUser = null;


if ($getUserPasswordResult = $mysqli->query($getUserPasswordQuery);)
{
    echo "GOT HERE";
    // Query was successful
}
$getUserPasswordResult->free(); // Line 66 (See below)
```

I'm **not** getting the echo statement but I **am** getting the following in the logs (which is understandable if the query isn't working).

```
Call to a member function free() on a non-object in .../script.php on line 66
```

Can anyone shed any light on this & perhaps why it'd work on localserver & not in the wild. Also, am I doing this the right way or is there a more bulletproof paradigm?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `real_escape_string`? The proper way is [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) which are actually pretty easy to do with `mysqli`.

Comment: And, what if `free()` a method or a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `free` outside of the test to see if that variable is defined correctly:

```
if ($getUserPasswordResult = $mysqli->query($getUserPasswordQuery);)
{
    echo "GOT HERE";
    // Query was successful
    $getUserPasswordResult->free(); // Line 66 (See below)
}
```

Comment: I knew that tadman, I was wondering how my localhost 'knew' about `$getUserPasswordResult` but I assumed it was some peculiarity with php (I'm a Java person). The fact that it works on my localhost is totally bizarre. But yes, this fixed it. Thanks

Comment: Maybe on your local machine it's always defined, and on your other machine it is only sometimes defined. Since you're not getting the `echo`, it's probably undefined.

Comment: Upon further investigation, turns out my localhost is **case insensitive** to table names `User` and my production environment is **case sensitive** 'user' ... All working now.

Comment: MySQL table names are subject to the same case sensitivity rules for files. As far as I know, Windows and OS X default to case insensitive, where Linux and BSD tend to be case sensitive.